# Dataframe conditional replacement with intigers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column like this:

```
df['col_name'].unique()
>>>array([-1, 'Not Passed, On the boundary', 1, 'Passed, On the boundary',
       'Passed, Unclear result', 'Passes, Unclear result, On the boudnary',
       'Rejected, Unclear result'], dtype=object)
```

In this column,
if an element contains the word 'Passed' as a field or as a substring, then replace the entire field with integer 1 else replace it with integer -1.

Kindly help me with this

Comment: there is no "positive" word in your example (also please provide a reproducible sample of the DataFrame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.str.contains` to check if value contains string and fill the NaN caused by integer value to `False`. Then use `np.where` to fill the `True` with 1 and `False` with 0. If you want to keep the original 1 and -1, you can try `np.select`.

```py
m1 = df['col_name'].str.contains('Passed').fillna(False)
m2 = df['col_name'].isin([1, -1])

df['col_name_replace_1_-1'] = np.where(m1, 1, -1)
df['col_name_keep_1_-1'] = np.select([m2, m1, ~m1], [df['col_name'], 1, -1], default=df['col_name'])
```

```
print(df)

                                  col_name  col_name_replace_1_-1 col_name_keep_1_-1
0                                       -1                     -1                 -1
1              Not Passed, On the boundary                      1                  1
2                                        1                     -1                  1
3                  Passed, On the boundary                      1                  1
4                   Passed, Unclear result                      1                  1
5  Passes, Unclear result, On the boudnary                     -1                 -1
6                 Rejected, Unclear result                     -1                 -1
```

Comment: I think this will fail in the cases were a value is already 1

Comment: @PaulH if value is 1, it doesn't contain the word 'Passed'. According to OP's statement, it should be replaced with integer -1.

Comment: I got the feeling the existing -1's and 1s should stay in place. I might be wrong about that

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for pointing out that, just tested that `.str.contains()` works on integer results in `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].apply(lambda x: 1 if 'Positive' in x else -1)
```

This checks each entry in `df['col_name']`, checks if the string contains `'Positive'` and replaces it with 1 or -1 appropriately. This obviously assumes that all entries in this column are `str`

Comment: if we're assuming everything is a string, `df[col].str.contains("Passed")` would be better.

Comment: All the entries are not strings. There are a few strings and a few integers.